# Pitfalls in C# for a new user. (FWHM calculation)

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my idea to program a simple math module (function) that can be called from another main program. It calculates the FWHM(full width at half the max) of a curve. Since this is my first try at Visual Studio and C#. I would like to know few basic programming structures I should learn in C# coming from a Mathematica background.

1. Is *double fwhm(double[] data, int c)* indicate the input arguments
   to this function fwhm should be a double data array and an Integer
   value? Did I get this right?
2. I find it difficult to express complex mathematical equations (line 32/33) to express them in parenthesis and divide one by another, whats the right method to do that?
3. How can I perform Mathematical functions on elements of an Array like division and store the results in the same Array?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DEV_2
{
    class fwhm
    {
      static double fwhm(double[] data, int c) // data as 2d data and c is integer
      {
        double[] datax;
        double[] datay;
        int L;
        int Mag = 4;
        double PP = 2.2;
        int CI;
        int k;
        double Interp;
        double Tlead;
        double Ttrail;
        double fwhm;
        L = datay.Length;

        // Create datax as index for the number of elemts in data from 1-Length(data).
        for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length; i++)
        {
            datax[i] = (i + 1);
        }

        //Find max in datay and divide all elements by maxValue.
        var m = datay.Length; // Find length of  datay
        Array.ForEach(datay, (x) => {datay[m++] = x / datay.Max();}); // Divide all elements of datay by max(datay)
        double maxValue = datay.Max();
        CI = datay.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue); // Push that index to CI

        // Start to search lead
        int k = 2;
        while (Math.Sign(datay[k]) == Math.Sign(datay[k-1]-0.5))
        {                
            k=k+1;
        }   
        Interp = (0.5-datay[k-1])/(datay[k]-datay[k-1]);
        Tlead = datax[k-1]+Interp*(datax[k]-datax[k-1]);
        CI = CI+1;

        // Start search for the trail
        while (Math.Sign(datay[k]-0.5) == Math.Sign(datay[k-1]-0.5) && (k<=L-1))
        {
            k=k+1;
        }
        if (k != L)
        {
            Interp = (0.5-datay[k-1])/(datay[k]-datay[k-1]);
            Ttrail = datax[k-1] + Interp*(datax[k]-datax[k-1]);
            fwhm =((Ttrail-Tlead)*PP)/Mag;
        }
    }//end main
  }//end class 
}//end namespace
```

Comment: 1. Yes, you are correct. 
2. Mark that line with comment in code
3. for example 5th element of array multiplied by 8 and then divided by 6 :) `array[5] = (array[5]*8)/6;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of pitfalls in C#, but working through problems is a great way to find and learn them!

1. Yes, when passing parameters to a method the correct syntax is `MethodName(varType varName)` seperated by a comma for multiple parameters. Some pitfalls arise here with differences in passing Value types and Reference types. If you're interested [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is some reading on the subject.
2. Edit: As pointed out in the comments you should write code as best as possible to require as few comments as possible (thus paragraph between #3 and #4), however if you need to do very specific and slightly complex math then you should comment to clarify what is occuring. 
   If you mean difficulties understanding, make sure you comment your code properly. If you mean difficulties writing it, you can create variables to simplify reading your code (but generally unnecessary) or look up functions or libraries to help you, this is a bit open ended question if you have a particular functionality you are looking for perhaps we could be of more help.
3. You can access your array via indexes such as `array[i]` will get the ith index. Following this you can manipulate the data that said index is pointing to in any way you wish, `array[i] = (array[i]/24)^3` or `array[i] = doMath(array[i])`

A couple things you can do if you like to clean a little, but they are preference based, is not declare `int CI; int k;` in your code before you initialize them with `int k = 2;`, there is no need (although you can if it helps you). The other thing is to correctly name your variables, common practice is a more descriptive camelCase naming, so perhaps instead of `int CI = datay.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue);` you coud use `int indexMaxValueYData = datay.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue);`

4. As per your comment question "What would this method return?" The method will return a double, as declared above. `returnType methodName(parameters)` However you need to add that in your code, as of now I see no return line. Such as `return doubleVar;` where doubleVar is a variable of type double.

Comment: I have edited the code and figured out all my errors, how can I check if this code is correct (like a test run) in visual studio by give pseudo input values ? Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do that, and they can differ depending on your setup. What kind of application did you create? Is it an MVC? If you so you can run it in debug and just create an Index that will be run and call your fhwm method and pass the values you'd like to test. Otherwise there are other ways, need more info  =)

Comment: I am trying to create a WFA, functionality is to import an image and calculate the above code to every column of that image. I have done this in Mathematica and want to implement that in C#. So my idea was to import some image and get its data as 2D data and insert that into the above code with let's say c value as 1 (column 1) and it would give me a number. The main program would import the image and do it for all the columns. zip file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MvsAKaAfj-bVlobl8zR1M5NzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds fun! You can simply run the WFA (make sure you built/are in debug mode) and call the function via `fwhm(data, c)` provided data and c are of the correct type in your main method. Good luck!

Comment: "If you mean difficulties understanding, make sure you comment your code properly" No no no no no! Write the code clearly so it doesn't need commenting! @abhilashsukumari, as soon as I reached `// Create datax as index for the number`, my instant reaction was "this should be its own function". Having to write comments inside a function is a sure sign the function needs rewriting, likely by splitting it in to many smaller functions.

Comment: Agreed, but the question at hand was how to understand lines of a mathematical nature. You can create another function, but you would still have to comment THAT function to understand what you are doing, or look up libraries/built in functions that will do what you are trying to achieve with simpler syntax...Rewrite code to understand without comments, baring that then comment so you know whats going on!